# I can't input a string with spaces

Tags: c, string, compilation

I'm writing a program and I need the user to input a line like this (`1, Stelios, 1.81, Greece`).

First thing I thought was use `gets()` because I want to accept space inputs . After a few tries compiling it without success I read that it was removed from C-11 because of dangers.

Next thing I did was use `scanf()` and `fgets()` but it skips input like they were never there and nothing seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f;     
    char line[30];
    char name[30]; 

    printf("\nGive the name: \n");
    scanf("%s", name);  
    f = fopen(name, "w");
    printf("\nGive the line to enter file: ");

    //gets(line);
    //fgets(line, 50, stdin);
    //scanf ("%[^\n]", line);
    //scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);

    printf("%s", line);        
    fclose(f);
}
```

That's everything I tried.

Comment: "it skips input like they were never there" because of prior (not displayed) code.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: Your best bet is `fgets`.  It's probably "skipping input like they were never there" because there's a newline left on the input stream, that wasn't consumed by some previous call you made to `scanf`.  This is one of the super annoying foibles of `scanf` -- it doesn't play well with later calls to `fgets`.

Comment: I used them one at a time not all together. None works, not gets or fgets or scanf.

Comment: fgets() works just fine--it's your code that's broken. But if you don't show it to us, we can't help you.

Comment: Okay sorry just a sec

Comment: Tried all of the things that i commented.

Comment: i dont know why but i wrote scanf ("%[^\n]", line); but scanf (" %[^\n]", line); worked. That space after the " did the job.

Comment: That space in the format string caused it to consume some whitespace that was left over on the input stream from the `scanf("%s", name)` call, which is what we've been trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `getchar();` after `scanf("%s", name);` then get the line you want with gets()